# How can I align these HTML components?

Tags: html, css

I've got 2 views, one for logged in and one for logged out. The logged out view I think is OK:

[image]

When logged in, the components do not align properly, as can be seen the user picture displays too far to the left:

[image]

Can you tell me what I need to do to achieve more aligned graphics? I think the user picture and the logo should be aligned the same. The code is:

```
<div id="header">
    <a id="logo" href="/" name="logo"><img src="/_/img/kool_business.png" height="80"
    title="Koolbusiness.com" alt="Koolbusiness.com" /></a>

    <div id="page_name" class="ctext1">
        <div class="ctext2">
            <div class="ctext3">
                For sale
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="line"></div>
</div>

<div id="container_main">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div style="float:left; margin-top:6px;">
            <img src=
            "https://graph.facebook.com/327400016/picture?type=small" /><a href=
            "/user/niklas-rosencrantz">Niklas Rosencrantz</a><span style=
            "color:#99ccff">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span><a href="/">Home</a><span style=
            "color:#99ccff">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span> <a href="/ai">Insert
            ad</a><span style="color:#99ccff">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span> <a href=
            "/tamil_nadu">Search for ads</a><span style=
            "color:#99ccff">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span> <a href=
            "/li?t=w">Wanted</a><span style="color:#99ccff">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
            <a href="/auth/logout">Log out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should I just remove the `style:"float:left; margin-top:6px` or what do you think I should do the present the layout smoother? The CSS for my page is

```
#header {
    margin-left: 26px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    width: 790px;
    height: 70px;
}
#logo,
#page_name {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
}
#page_name {
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 250px;
}
#logo { margin-right: 26px }
.navbar {
    margin: 5px 0 10px -7px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar a,
.navbar a:visited,
.navbar a:link {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #336699;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar a:hover { text-decoration: none }
.navbar a:active { text-decoration: underline }
```

Thanks in advance for any answer or comment

Comment: Where do you want the picture to appear?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I suppose I want the layout just smoother so aligned with the loga above will do. Following Scott's answer it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image inside the anchor tag for the name rather than outside it.

Comment: Happy to help. It makes more sense to users to be able to click the photo as well as the name, too. So you'll increase usability with the image inside the anchor tag as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have `margin-left: -7px` on `.nav` and then counter-act it with `margin-left: 8px` on the anchor tags inside the nav div, but never do so with the `img`.

Can you get rid of the -7px left margin in `.nav` or do you have it there for another reason?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can try this answer too while the answer from Scott above worked already.

Comment: No problem. I think you should use Scott's answer and put the image inside the anchor tag as it would be more user friendly (in my opinion). But I would also get rid of the negative margin if you do not need it.